# PhantomJS facebook login form not fully submitted

Tags: javascript, facebook, web-scraping, phantomjs, form-submit

I am trying to login to facebook by phantomJS, it is working fine but when I run it do not submit form.

It opens page fills fields but do not submits. I tried console to see form submit it return undefined first then it submits.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var stepIndex = 0;
var loadInProgress = false;

email = system.args[1];
password = system.args[2];

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log("load finished");
};

var steps = [
    function() {
        page.open("http://www.facebook.com/login.php", function(status) {
            page.evaluate(function(email, password) {
                document.querySelector("input[name='email']").value = email;
                document.querySelector("input[name='pass']").value = password;

                document.querySelector("#login_form").submit();

                console.log("Login submitted!");
            }, email, password);
            page.render('output.png');
        });
    },
    function() {
        console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
    },
    function() {
        phantom.exit();
    }
]

setInterval(function() {
    if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[stepIndex] == "function") {
        console.log("step " + (stepIndex + 1));
        steps[stepIndex]();
        stepIndex++;
    }
    if (typeof steps[stepIndex] != "function") {
        console.log("test complete!");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two problems.

- Since submitting a form usually incurs some network requests, the result won't be available immediately, but you're assuming that it will be immediately available, because you're immediately rendering a screenshot to see what happened. That screenshot won't show you the page after the submit. It will show you a page during a submit. You need to move the rendering to the next step when the submit result arrived in the browser.
- `document` has no meaning outside of the page context. PhantomJS will nevertheless provide such a dummy object. You can only access the DOM (`document` and `window`) inside of `page.evaluate()`.

Try

```
var steps = [
    function() {
        page.open("http://www.facebook.com/login.php", function(status) {
            page.evaluate(function(email, password) {
                document.querySelector("input[name='email']").value = email;
                document.querySelector("input[name='pass']").value = password;

                document.querySelector("#login_form").submit();

                console.log("Login submitted!");
            }, email, password);
        });
    },
    function() {
        page.render('output.png');
        console.log("innerHTML: " + page.evaluate(function(){
            return document.documentElement.innerHTML;
        }));
        console.log("full page: " + page.content);
    },
    function() {
        phantom.exit();
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, You are perfect, When I referred page in other function I  was getting page is not a variable / undefine but yours working great. @Artjom B.

Comment: B, thanks for great support. I am able to login on this page by help of your answer but why cant it works for www.facebook.com homepage to login. It only works for www.facebook.com/login.php

Comment: I don't know. Maybe there is some kind of redirect which PhantomJS is unable to perform.